# Getting unexpected TypeErrorwhen trying to find element on page by text

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using a wait function to make Selenium search for the presence of an element on the page by its text before it continues to take actions. I am trying to pass the text that I am searching for into my function, however, I keep getting "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable", which is odd because I am looking for a string! I've tried everything I can think of, even escape sequences, but nothing seems to make it work. Please find my code below:

```
self.webdriver_wait(action = 'find_text', keys_to_pass = 'Financial Documents')

def webdriver_wait(self, selector = '#body', action='', keys_to_pass=''):
    try:
            WebDriverWait(self.browser, 240).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH("//*[contains(text(), \' + str(keys_to_pass) + \'')]"))))
```

Answer (score 1):

`By.XPATH` is not a method, but a simple string (`By.XPATH == 'xpath'`), you need to use it as below:

```
WebDriverWait(self.browser, 240).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), '%s')]" % keys_to_pass)))
```

Comment: Thanks for this @Andersson, though I'm still getting the same error when using this. I was able to make it work by changing my code like so: WebDriverWait(self.browser, 240).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*"))).text == keys_to_pass

Comment: @Gregory , *make it work*... Make work what ?! :) Your code just waiting for *first* element in DOM  (`html`) and checks if its text is `keys_to_pass`. It makes no sense actually

Comment: I don't follow--shouldn't using that xpath be searching the body text for my string in the above example?

Comment: @Gregory , did you get `TimeOutException` with my code or `TypeError`? Can you share HTML of element which you want to select by its text?